# Jquery get element ID from its value

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid

Hey guys I have a problem in Jquery. I need to get the id of an element from its value.
I have to find the ID of the element having maximum value.

```
 var M = Math.max($("#textbox1").val(), 
         $("#textbox8").val(),
         $("#textbox15").val(),
         $("#textbox22").val(),
         $("#textbox29").val(), 
         $("#textbox36").val(), 
         $("#textbox43").val(), 
         $("#textbox50").val());
```

Now suppose I get the maximum value to be of textbox1 and I get that value in M.

Now I need to find the ID of element depending on the value in M and then change the color of that textbox.
How to do it?
Am doing like this but its not working :

```
var pp = $(this).attr(M, 'id');
```

Comment: You really don't need to use `filter()` here at all. I don't know if you looked at my answer at all, but it's a much faster and easier solution. You don't even need the element's ID either (as my answer also states).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var id = $('input:text').filter(function(){
    return this.value === M.toString();
}).prop('id');
```

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to display table in stack overflow. when I copy it is shown as text bt i want to display it in a way so that others can see it as table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) (`[name="value"]`). Suppose you have these HTML values:

```html
<input id="textbox1" value="2" />
<input id="textbox2" value="5" />
<input id="textbox3" value="3" />
```

To get the ID of the element with the largest value (textbox2, in this case), you'd you'd use:

```js
var M = 5; /* As calculated */
$('input[value="' + M + '"]')[0].id; /* textbox2 */
```

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/WzN36/).

It's worth noting that selecting the attribute is [more than 80% faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-filter-vs-attribute-selector) than using `filter()`.

---

Also, you don't *need* the ID to change the colour of the text box, either. You can again use the above selector:

```js
$('input[value="' + M + '"]').css({
    color: '#f00'
});
```

See this modified [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WzN36/1/).

Answer (score 0):

A bit convoluted, but if you have the max value, you can get all the textboxes, filter by the one who has that value and change the color:

```
$('input[type="text"]').filter(function(index) {
    return $(element).val() == M
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: you should change `'text'` to `"text"` otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks! I typed to fast, so overlooked that one :P